# Background color of tkinter label will not change (python 3.4)

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am making a widget with Tkinter in python 3.4. For some reason, I cannot change a label's background color from the default grey. The code for the label is something like this:

```
self.label = ttk.Label(master, text="Label Text", 
                       foreground="blue", background="yellow")
```

Everything else works fine. I can change the foreground (text) color, however the background will not change, whether I am using label.config(), label['background'], or whatever.

I can change the background if I write it for Python 2.7, but I am using tutorials for Tkinter in 3.4, so this is undesirable.

Comment: If you're wanting to create customized labels, have you considered  using the standard Label rather than the ttk one?

Comment: That does work. I'm just trying to follow along with a tutorial on lynda.com, so I'm not sure why they used ttk. But the fact that it wasn't working for me, while I see it working in the video is frustrating. Perhaps I need to find a better tutorial as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This bug is caused by the 'aqua' ttk style on Mac OSX.  It also breaks 'ttk.Progressbar' when set to 'indeterminate' mode.  To fix both issues insert the following code after 'root = Tk()' to change the style ...

```
style = ttk.Style()
style.theme_use('classic') # Any style other than aqua.
```

This solution was posted by dietrich41 
here : http://www.python-forum.org/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=16212

I tested it on a Mac running Python 3.4.1.

Comment: Before down-voting this answer please remember that this is an issue specific to tkinter on a Mac running Python 3.4.  The only solution I have found is to not use Aqua.