# Changing color of buttons in tkinter works on Windows but not Mac OSX

Tags: python, macos, tkinter

**Edit: I tried it on Windows and it works, I guess it is a OSX bug?**

The following code does not work for some reason and the button stays white

```
z = Button(frame, text="Nothing Scheduled", bg = "blue" command=lambda ..., width=15)
z.grid(row=x, column=1)
```

However, setting the background of a label works correctly for some reason like below

```
Label(frame, text=times[x], bg="blue").grid(row=x, column=0)
```

So I end up with the following GUI, shown below

[image]

I am aware of the bug detailed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28589021/background-color-of-tkinter-label-will-not-change-python-3-4) post, however I am not using ttk so I don't think that applies here. I am simply using `from tkinter import *` in Python 3.6.4, however I am on Mac OSX

I have also tried `z.config(bg="blue")` as well as `z["bg"]="blue"`, and both of those fail as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this [page](http://wiki.tcl.tk/44444)  of the tcl/tk wiki are listed some problems related to Mac and the color of labels and buttons's backgrounds. For example:

> ...
>
> The Mac OS X background color should not be white, it should be #ececec. Since winfo rgb does not work properly on the mac colors, this makes it difficult to get the proper default color.
>
> ... etc.

Saludos!,

Answer (score 3):

for python3, try

```
pip3 install tkmacosx
```

Then it should be work with this:

```
from tkmacosx import Button as button
B1 = button(frame, text = 'Hello!', bg = 'black', fg = 'white',command = testing)
```

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same problem on osx 10.14.3, then I replace with the ttk button, and it works!

```
from tkinter import ttk
b1 = ttk.Button(root, text="start", width=15, command=begin)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [tkmacosx](https://pypi.org/project/tkmacosx/) Library it allows you to change the button color in MacOSX.

### Install

```
pip install tkmacosx
```

### Example

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkmacosx import Button

root = Tk()
root.geometry("200x200")
B1 = Button(root, text='Button', bg='red')
B1.grid(row=0, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

### Result

[To see the result click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7NeL.png)