# tkinter using default Mac theme

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-3.9, tkinter-layout

i am working on a tkinter app and I just updated to the latest version of python(python 3.9.5) and tkinter is using my mac's default theme, which doesn't go with my design.

i want this(the light theme):
[image]

but what am getting is(the dark theme):
[image]

is there a way I can change the theme to `light` or to check the current mac theme?

my code:

```
from tkinter import *

class Snipper:

    def __init__(self):
       self.root = Tk()
       self.root.title("snipper")

       self.build()

       # bring app to front after start
       self.root.lift()
       self.root.attributes('-topmost',True)
       self.root.after_idle(self.root.attributes,'-topmost',False)

       self.root.minsize(1000, 600)
       self.root.mainloop()



 s = Snipper()
```

Comment: Is this a problem for all widgets, or are you just asking how to get a white background on the root window?

Comment: i tried with button and text widgets they are both dark. so yeah I think it is a problem for all widgets that come shipped with tkinter and ttk. and also asking for how to change theme(get white background on root and title window).

Comment: @NahuGere so ```self.root.configure(bg = "white")``` doesn't work for you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing color of buttons in tkinter works on Windows but not Mac OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51014756/changing-color-of-buttons-in-tkinter-works-on-windows-but-not-mac-osx)

Comment: no this is not what i was looking for